# awk - collecting the similar lines in a single line

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, awk

I have a file:

**input.txt**:

```
a_1_bcd
ab_1_e
i_2_gxyz
la_3_df
de_3_fg
ff_3_hi
```

I treat a part between the first and second underscores as ID and I want to put all the lines sharing the same ID in a single line. Note: before doing this, I'll have to surround the line by "<" and ">" chars.

So, I want to get

**output.txt**:

```
<a_1_bcd><ab_1_e>
<i_2_gxyz>
<la_3_df><de_3_fg><ff_3_hi>
```

This looks simple, and I found some way of doing this using loops and arrays, but my solution looks ugly, and I want to ask: how would you solve this effectively and easily?

Comment: Then first show your solution

Comment: use `match` to select a part between undercores; let's name it `x`; save as arr[x]; and in the end, for length(arr) for length(arr[x]) print "<" arr[x] ">"...

Comment: I meant save $0 as arr[x], of course :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F_ '!a[$2]{b[++k]=$2} {a[$2]=a[$2] "<" $0 ">"}
            END {for (i=1; i<=k; i++) print a[b[i]]}' file
<a_1_bcd><ab_1_e>
<i_2_gxyz>
<la_3_df><de_3_fg><ff_3_hi>
```

- Uses 2 associative arrays: a where ID is key and value is all the corresponding lines
- array `b` is used for keeping original order of keys only
- For every line values of same key are joined together using `a[$2] "<" $0 ">"` expression.

---

**Simplified version that doesn't keep ordering intact:**

```
awk -F_ '{a[$2]=a[$2] "<" $0 ">"} END{for (i in a) print a[i]}' file
<i_2_gxyz>
<la_3_df><de_3_fg><ff_3_hi>
<a_1_bcd><ab_1_e>
```

Comment: Isn't `'{a[$2]=a[$2]"<"$0">"}END{for (i in a){print a[i]}}'` sufficient?

Comment: That will print the content but **ordering** will be different, see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. My output was in order so I didn't pay attention…